# Python draw overlay on screen using WX in linux mint

Tags: python, overlay, wxwidgets

I'm trying to draw an simple square on screen as an overlay using python and wx in linux mint.
I've tried :

```
import wx
app = wx.App(False)
s = wx.ScreenDC()
s.StartDrawingOnTop()
s.Pen = wx.Pen("#00FF00")
s.DrawRectangle(60,60,120,120)
s.EndDrawingOnTop()
```

But without success. Any hint's or ideas are highly appreciated.

L.E.:

```
Python 2.7.18 (default, Mar  8 2021, 13:02:45) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux2
>>> import wx
>>> wx.version()
'3.0.2.0 gtk3 (classic)'
```

Display : X11

Comment: what is your {wx}ython versions? Is it using GTK2 or GTK3? Do you have Wayland or X11?

Comment: Edited post with required info,